# Clojure - Codeexamples to show off software transactional memory

Tags: clojure, transactions, stm

I created some exercises to show the capabilties and funcionality of the clojure stm. Are they good enough, or are there better ways to show the benefits of stm?

My work:

**Item transfer**

1. Define the three characters as follows:

   ```
   (def smaug (ref {:life 500, :atk 50, :def 25, :alive true, :items (set(range 100))))
   (def bilbo (ref {:life 250, :atk 35, :def 12, :alive true, :items ()}))
   (def gandalf (ref {:life 300, :atk 27, :def 8, :mana 50, :alive true, :items ()}))
   ```

Now implement an appropriate function to transfer one of a character's :items to one of the other characters.

2. Now that you can easily transfer `:items` from one character to another, start two threads, one for bilbo and one for gandalf, and let both threads transfer `:items` from smaug to bilbo and gandalf until smaug has no `:items` left.
3. Why does the following transaction throw an exception?

   ```
   (dosync
       @(future (dosync 
           (alter bilbo update-in [:items] conj (first (get @smaug :items))) 
               (alter smaug update-in [:items] disj (first (get @smaug :items))))) 
   (alter gandalf update-in [:items] conj (first (get @smaug :items)))
   (alter smaug update-in [:items] disj (first (get @smaug :items))))
   ```

**Battle system**

1. Start over with three characters from the beginning. Now implement a function which simulates a battle between two characters. Therefore the `:atk` value of the attacker minus the `:def` value of the defender is subtracted from the `:life` value of the defender. Per battle there is only one attacker and one defender.
   Now let one of the characters fight against `smaug` and if one defeats smaug, he gets all of his `:items`. Keep in mind that the :life value shall never be smaller than 0!!!
   If the `:life` value of a character is 0, the character is dead. Therefore the `:alive` value is set to false.
2. As you might have noticed can no character defeat `smaug` by his own. Lucky, `gandalf` can heal other characters. But first you have to implement a function, which lets `gandalf` heal `bilbo`. Therefore the `:life` value is increased. Simultanously healing decreases `gandalf's` `:mana`. If his `:mana` reaches 0 he can;t heal. Now let `gandalf` heal `bilbo` after every battle. Now that both characters are involved in the battle, both shall receive `:items` from `smaug`. Keep in mind that the `:mana` value should never be smaller than 0. `Bilbos` `:life` value should never be smaller than 0 too!!!
3. Now we want to make the game more dynamic. We want to make the `:atk` value of `bilbo` and `gandalf` depending of the day time.
   Now implement day cycle. To represent the day time define an integer value as a `ref`. This value should be updated every second in a seperate thread. Therefore attle and day cycle are executed by seperated threads. Every update increments the day time by 1. The maximum value is 23.
   If it is day (6 – 17),  bilbo und gandalf get a bonus of 1/3 of their `:atk` value. At night (18 - 5) they get a negative bonus of 1/3.

Comment: smaug,bilbo,gandalf -  isn't that taken from [Clojure Programming](https://books.google.at/books?id=nZTvSa4KqfQC&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=clojure+smaug+bilbo&source=bl&ots=0W4pAM4Mqe&sig=Kt9N3UDS9xby3y-u3qQA58pgNLU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu-dn00prUAhVHVhQKHZyNCSQQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=clojure%20smaug%20bilbo&f=false) page 181ff ? If it is, why not check the book?

Comment: yes it is from the book, but there isn't an answer to my question.
but I wanted to hear some other opinions about this.

Comment: I read it through a few times, spotted the syntax errors in the code snippets, scrached my head and finally I'm still wondering: What is the question ? Where is the problem ? If it is just `Are they (the examples) good enough?` - you did not really provide the `for what` part. What kind of answer are you looking for ?

Comment: The question is `Are the examples good enough to summarize the functions of the stm to people who are trying to get into this subject?`